# how do I force a refresh of whatever cache is preventing ssh connection to noip home computer?

Tags: networking, openssh

I've noticed that I cannot always connect from WiFi hotspots to my home computer. Often I can but sometimes not. I hadn't worried much about some WiFi hotspots not working, because I had assumed that they're blocking outgoing ssh, but maybe something else is going on?

I'm using termux on my phone to control my home computer.

Anyway, recently I tried to connect, couldn't, and instructed the kids to unplug and replug the router/modem. That didn't resolve the issue, so waited to get home.

But now I'm home and still can't connect! I'm on the same WiFi network even!

I can ping, just like I could from that WiFi hotspot on the other side of town, but ssh gives the same error of "no route to host" which makes no damn sense to me at all.

So why am I still getting that error? What do I force a refresh to and how to clear it?

I can connect to the my home router with a browser, (now that I'm on my home wifi) and have verified that I'm pinging my externally visible ip address, and it's correct, and had been the whole time.

I've connected via ssh dozens of times a day for years, now it fails? I connected fine this morning! Why change? I'm able to connect from some WiFi hotspots, but not others, why?

I was thinking it's a dns error of some sort (given I'm using noip) but... It has the right ip address? Ssh is using ipv4, just like ping is (the -6 option gives "no address associated with hostname", -4 gives same error message)

Comment: Does power cycling your phone help? When you `ping` are you using the ip address or the name? If you are using the name and the ping works this seems to rule out DNS issues assuming the same resolver library for both ping and ssh. If you are using the address can you use that with ssh?

Comment: Power cycle on phone didn't help. Given what they problem was, power cycle on computer would have, but clicking on icon to re-enable networking worked fine too. Using both noip name and ipv4 address today were same.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall problems aren't the only thing that can make a computer available but unresponsive.

In this case, one of the kids had disabled networking on the computer. Since the router is available, I can ping it. But since the computer (designated as the DMZ) is offline, no actual services are available.

Thus the "no route to host" when the host is clearly available.